# Second counter in SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, counter

I need to have a table like this:

```
CLIENT_ID ID CONTENT
--------------------
1         1  abc
1         2  abc
1         3  abc
2         1  abc
2         2  abc
2         3  abc
```

`client_id` and `id` are the table's pk. on the application side, only client `client_id` and `content` are known, so I thought to have an after insert trigger that updates the `id` column as needed, but I'm having troubles. any help? Thanks.

My first attempt was:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test
ON [dbo].[table]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @client_id INT;
    DECLARE @id INT;

    SELECT @client_id = client_id 
    FROM inserted;

    SELECT @id = ISNULL(MAX(clifor_id), 0) + 1 
    FROM table
    WHERE client_id = @client_id

    UPDATE [dbo].[table]
    SET [id] = @id
    WHERE ?????
END
```

but don't know how to complete it.

ps: sorry for my English!

Comment: What event should fire off the trigger?  How does a "second counter" relate to the table you've shown?  Please consider rephrasing your question as what you're asking isn't very clear.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some tips

Comment: Since you say you're trying, what is the code you have tried and what error did you get?

Comment: you will need to use a `instead of` trigger and not `after` trigger. The insert will failed if you don't supply an `id` column

Comment: Seems to me you are putting to much value in this ID column. Would be a LOT simpler to just use an identity. Is there some actual reason you need to have a sequential number per ClientID?

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is not the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once** and the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select from `Inserted`? It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Answer (score 1):

@Squirrel pointed you in good direction - *instead of* trigger is a way to go. S.t. like this one:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test
ON [dbo].[table]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE inserted
    SET id = (select 1+max(id) from dbo.table where client_id = inserted.client_id)

    INSERT INTO dbo.table
    SELECT * FROM inserted --note - you should rewrite this block so it will be with explicit list of columns
END
```

Note that this will fail if you can insert multiple entries for the same client in one query.